Kotlin Multiplatform iOS sourceSet doesn't run on XCode
While trying to run my KMM project, iOS source set using XCode, I'm receiving the next message:
Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 11 Xcode.
After running java --version
openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874, mixed mode)

Also I run ./gradlew --version
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-10-04 20:52:13 UTC
Revision:     e9251e572c9bd1d01e503a0dfdf43aedaeecdc3f

Kotlin:       1.9.10
Groovy:       3.0.17
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.13 compiled on January 4 2023
JVM:          17.0.9 (JetBrains s.r.o. 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874)
OS:           Mac OS X 14.4.1 x86_64

Also in Android studio I have set Java 17, none of that works, XCode still gives me the same error.

The only thing that worked for me was to add the next line in gradle.properties file
org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/home
In your case replace it with the path to your java artifact
